# TikZ datavisualization: Is it possible to change fontsize globally?

Tags: tikz-datavisualization

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}

\begin{document}

Text
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[
                       scientific axes = clean,
                       x axis = {
                                 label = {$\varepsilon$, einheitenlos}
                                },
                       y axis = {
                                 label = {$\epsilon$, in V}
                                },
                       visualize as smooth line = func,
                       func = {
                               label in legend = {text = $\epsilon(\varepsilon)$}
                              }
                      ]
    data[format = function] {
                             var x : interval[0 : .9];
                             func y = 1 / (1 - \value x) ^ 2;
                            };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: result]

Can one have the default fontsize of the documentclass (`11pt` in case of `scrartcl`, see the `KOMA-Script` manual on page 59) for both the figure (tics labels, legend and axis labels) and document text. The best solution for me would be to set up it with `TikZ datavisualization` options in the document preamble, but I didn't found anything about it in the `TikZ` manual. So is it possible? If not, than other solutions are welcome too.

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: How about `\documentclass[20pt]{scrartcl}`?

Comment: Hello @Matthias Arras! Thank you for your comment! My bad: My question wasn't precise enought. I wish for both the figure and the document text the default fontsize of the documentclass. This means I have to set up it with `TikZ datavisualization` options, but I didn't found anything about it in the `TikZ` manual. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `datavisualization` use the normal font size everywhere by adding

```latex
\tikzdatavisualizationset{
  use default font/.style={node style={font=}},
  every data set label/.append style={use default font},
  every axis label/.append style={use default font},
  every ticks/.append style={use default font},
  every legend inside/.append style={label style={use default font}},
}
```

to your preamble.

The defaults are

- `\small` for data set labels and axis labels,
- `\footnotesize` for ticks and legend inside.

Ti*k*Z defaults are pretty good, as a rule, so be careful when changing them.